# Django suffix ForeignKey field with _id

Tags: django, foreign-keys

Suppose I have a field f in my model defined as follows as a foreign key:

```
f = models.ForeignKey(AnotherModel)
```

When Django syncs database, the filed created in db will be called `f_id`, automatically suffixed with '_id'.

The problem is I want this field in db named exactly as what I defined in model, `f` in this case. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Well it turns out there's a keyword argument called `db_column`. If you want the field named 'f' in the database table, it's just as simple as:

```
f = models.ForeignKey(AnotherModel, db_column='f')
```

Further reference:

> The name of the database column to use for
> this field. If this isn't given, Django will use the field's name.
>
> If your database column name is an SQL reserved word, or contains
> characters that aren't allowed in Python variable names -- notably,
> the hyphen -- that's OK. Django quotes column and table names behind
> the scenes.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#db-column

Comment: I think you should make it clear that this `db_column` field option is needed in `AnotherModel`, probably together with `primary_key=True` on the `f` field.

Comment: Thanks @dschulz but what do you mean by 'this `db_column` field option is needed in `AnotherModel`'? Cuz i don't think what `f` is called in the database has anything to do with `AnotherModel`, am I right?

Comment: Oops! I was wrong @Caperea, sorry. My brainfart was about the name of the primary key column in `AnotherModel`. You're right, using the `db_column` field option on the `f` field should suffice.