# Django filter on OneToOne field appending "_id" and failing

Tags: python, mysql, django

In my Django application I have the following model:

```py
class Provider(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

Note `user` is a OneToOneField to my CustomUser table and also the primary key of this table.

In `views.py`, I attempt to query this table with `Provider.objects.filter(user=request.user)` and get `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'appname_provider.user_id' in 'field list'")`. Checking my MySql database, I see the columns are `(user, company_id)`. So why is Django adding "_id" to `user` when I try to filter?

My CustomUser model:

```py
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    is_provider = models.BooleanField()
    is_admin = models.BooleanField()
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["is_provider", "email"]
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.username)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116130/django-suffix-foreignkey-field-with-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116130/django-suffix-foreignkey-field-with-id)

Comment: @RobMoll This is different because here Django is not adding "_id" in the database, but rather in the query. I tried adding `db_column=user_id` but after migrating the column is still named `user` in mysql and the issue persists.

Comment: How does your `CustomUser` model look like? And how does `request.user` look like? Is it the ID of a user? Have you tried retrieving the instance before you query? E.g. `Provider.objects.filter(user=CustomUser.objects.get(pk=request.user))`? You can also use lookups which span relationships like `Provider.objects.filter(user__id=request.user)`. For both assuming you have the ID of the user.

Comment: @yvesonline request.user is a `<SimpleLazyObject: <CustomUser: username>>`, not an id, so those queries don't work. Unfortunately, even `Provider.objects.filter(user__id=request.user.id)` fails with the same error I originally had. Elsewhere I'm able to say `user=request.user` for tables where  `user` is a ForeignKey, because Django appends "_id", but it doesn't work with the OneToOne field. I added my `CustomUser` model to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved this issue:

1. Undo all migrations: `rm -rf appname/migrations/0* appname/__pycache__` and in mysql: `DELETE FROM django_migrations;`
2. Delete the `Provider` table in mysql: `DROP TABLE appname_provider;`
3. Recreate the `Provider` table in mysql with column `user_id` instead of `user`: `CREATE TABLE appname_provider (user_id INT PRIMARY KEY, company_id INT);`
4. Reset migrations for builtin apps: `python manage.py migrate --fake`
5. Make migrations for this app: `python manage.py makemigrations appname`
6. Fake run the migrations since all the tables are still in the database: `python manage.py migrate --fake`
7. I then needed to make `company_id` a foreign key because I hadn't done that in step 3, so in `Provider` I did `company = models.IntegerField()`, made and ran migrations, then set it back to `company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`, made and ran migrations again. This is a bit hacky, but without this change back and forth, Django did not detect that it had to make `company_id` a foreign key.

Now `Provider` contains a column `user_id` in the database instead of `user`, so the query works! Note with this approach you lose any data in the `Provider` table, but the rest of the database is preserved. I got some of the steps from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29898483/7632019.