# Django: Replace foreign key attribute name (as well as column name) “_id” suffix with “_code” or other suffix

Tags: python, django

My question is closely related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116130/django-suffix-foreignkey-field-with-id), yet subtly different.

Given the following Django models:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(primary_key=True)


class Person(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Note that I have specified a custom primary key field on `Country` called `code`. The `Country` class should have no `id` field or attribute. This is working fine.

And of course I want the `Person` class's foreign key to `Country` to use the `code` field. That is also working fine. So far so good.

However, I *also* really want the underlying *column name* in the `Person` table to be exactly `country_code`. *NOT* `country_id`. So I added the `db_column` field argument:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(
        Country, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        db_column='country_code',
    )
```

Now the column name is correctly named `country_code` instead of `country_id`. So far so good.

---

Now. In my python code, I want to be able to access a country via a person in the normal way:

```
person = Person.objects.get(...)
country = person.country
```

*BUT*, I want to be able to access the country code pk via a person using `country_code`, *not* `country_id`, like so:

```
person = Person.objects.get(...)
country_code = person.country_code
```

And I also want to be able to *create* Person objects with the `country_code` argument, not `country_id`:

```
person = Person(country_code='foo')
```

And I also want to be able to *query* for Person objects with the `country_code` argument, not `country_id`:

```
people = Person.objects.filter(country_code='foo')
```

There should be *no* `person.country_id` attribute, field, or column. Only `person.country` and `person.country_code`. And yes, I want that field/attribute/column to be called exactly `person.country_code`, *NOT* `person.country_id` even if it holds the same value. That's the exact name I want in both Python and in the RDBMS.

---

So far, I have not been able to achieve this. I have tried tinkering with adding the `to_field` argument to the `Person.country` field declaration like so:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(
        Country, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        to_field='code',
        db_column='country_code',
    )
```

This does not seem have the desired effect.

Is it possible to change a model's foreign key field *attribute* name (as well as the underlying column name) in Django?

This doesn't seem to me like like such a strange thing to do. Maybe I'm wrong. Is this possible? Is this just too hard/non-standard to be worth it? Am I asking for trouble?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### customize a foreignkey subclass

```
class NamedForeignKey(models.ForeignKey):
    suffix_idname = 'id'
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        suffix_idname = kwargs.pop('suffix_idname', None)
        if suffix_idname:
            self.suffix_idname = suffix_idname
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_attname(self):
        return '%s_%s' % (self.name, self.suffix_idname)

class Person(models.Model):
    country = NamedForeignKey(
        Country, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        suffix_idname='code',
    )
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for.